# Building a search criteria thats tricky?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am trying to do a search on my database IndividualRecords by first building a search criteria but its syntax is getting a little tricky for some values. Its easy to set a criteria for an exact field like if the firstName field has 'John' in it I would put this predicate in my criteria:

```
IndividualRecord.withCriteria {

    if (predicates.firstName != null) {
      eq 'firstName', predicates.firstName
    }
}
```

But if they also add that they want to search for US citizens, I can't simply do,

```
if (predicates.UScitizenship) {
      eq 'citizenship', predicates.citizenship
    }
```

because I want to look for records based on citizenship 'US', 'Us', 'uS', and 'us'(case insensitivity must be taken in to account) so how would I get around this?

and then here is where the real fun starts. Say I want to find only foreign citizens. I do have a low level mongodb api method that tells me if the citizenship is a valid one by returning true if it finds it in the database of country codes that I have so I guess I could build another predicate something like pseudocode:

```
if (predicates.foreign) {
      all such people whose !citizenship.caseIgnoreEquals('US') && matchCountry(it.citizenship)
}
```

meaning that all such people whose citizenship isn't 'US' and matches the list of country codes I have where `matchCountry(String countryCode)` is my low level api method for verifying a country code and will return true if its a valid country code.

I am finding it hard to define such complicated predicates' syntax and that is where I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues at hand here.

First, case sensitivity and insensitivy can be addressed by using ilike instead of equals. So for example:

```
if (predicates.firstName != null) {
  ilike 'firstName', predicates.firstName
}
```

Secondly, you may want to look at [named queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) to encapsulate some of your query definitions. This way you can include/exclude them as you see fit. For example:

```
if (predicates.foreign) {
  foreignPersons(predicates) // call to named query which contains logic
}
```

Using this you should be able to construct very complex queries which are built upon smaller definitions and in turn make them more usable and reusable.

Comment: Named query sounds like a good tool but I am still at a loss to see how to write up the syntax for the case of the foreign query. It seems recursive to put a named query in the IndividualRecord class that reads: foreignPersons { IndividualRecord such that their citizenship property(a String) isn't like 'US' AND it is a valid country in the database as per my matchCountry(it.citizenship) function returning 'true'}. This syntax is what I need help with.

Comment: Just kind of making up my own syntax here: `class IndividualRecord { String citizenship static namedQueries = {
   foreignIndividuals {
    inotlike 'citizenship', 'US'
    isTrue, matchCountry(citizenship)
   }
  }}` Sorry, I don't know how to type properly formatted code in a comment but that is the gist of the syntax I need. Furthermore, matchCountry is a method I have defined in a service so is it allowed in a static named query definition?